# How to send email with zend framework

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

I am using Zend API to send emails but after many tests still can not send any email.

**This is my script:**

```
set_include_path( get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.dirname(__FILE__).'/lib');
set_include_path( get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.dirname(__FILE__).'/lib/Zend');
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
ini_set("max_execution_time",0);
session_save_path(dirname(__FILE__));
include_once 'SMTPMailer.php';
include_once 'email_validation.php';

.....

$validator=new email_validation_class();
$smtpMailer = new SMTPMailer();
if ($smtpMailer->sendEmails($to,$attachmentArray) === true) {
    print '<font size="5" color="#0000FF"> ... Successfull!</font><br>';
} else {
    print '<font color="#FF0000"> ... Aborted!</font><br>';
}
```

after runing the script the output is **"... Aborted!"**.

**This is Zend sendEmails function:**

```
public function sendEmails($to,$attachment = array ()) {
    try{
        $this->mailer = new Zend_Mail ();
        var_dump($this->smtpTransport);
        if ($this->mailType == 'html') {

            $this->mailer->setBodyHtml($this->getMailBody());
        }else{
            $this->mailer->setBodyText($this->getMailBody());
        }

        $this->mailer->setFrom($this->mailFromEmail, $this->mailFrom);
        $this->mailer->addTo($to);
        $this->mailer->setSubject($this->mailSubject);
        if (!empty($attachment)) {
            $this->mailer->createAttachment($attachment['data'],$attachment['type'],Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,$attachment['name']);
        }

        $this->mailer->send($this->smtpTransport);
        return true;
    } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

this is the output of `var_dump($this->smtpTransport)`

> Sending mail to david@gmail.com ...object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp)#3
>   (15) { ["EOL"]=> string(1) " " ["_host":protected]=> string(27)
>   "smtpout.supvttor2026.com" ["_port":protected]=> string(2) "25"
>   ["_name":protected]=> string(9) "localhost" ["_auth":protected]=>
>   string(5) "login" ["_config":protected]=> array(4) { ["auth"]=>
>   string(5) "login" ["username"]=> string(24) "info@supvttor2026.com"
>   ["password"]=> string(9) "david1976" ["port"]=> string(2) "25" }
>   ["_connection":protected]=> NULL ["body"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["boundary"]=> string(0) "" ["header"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["_headers":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_isMultipart":protected]=>
>   bool(false) ["_mail":protected]=> bool(false) ["_parts":protected]=>
>   array(0) { } ["recipients"]=> string(0) "" }

my credentials are correct , domain , user ,password and port are perfect.
can you help me to find out where is my problem

Comment: Can you show message from exception?

Comment: thanks chaoss88 for the reply , the message from exception is : Could not open socket .

Comment: are you using ssl?

Comment: no , i am not using ssl